# Aligning a Stack pointer 8 byte from 4 byte in ARM assembly

Tags: c, memory, arm

How do I align a stack pointer to 8 byte which is now 4 byte aligned in ARM .As per my understanding stack pointer is 4 byte aligned if it points to some address like 0x4 ,0x8,0x12 and 0x16 so on.

So ,aliging a stack pointer to 8 byte means it should point to addresses like 0x8 ,0x16 ,0x24 and 0x32 and so on.

Now how Do I aligned 4 byte stack pointer to 8 byte aligned pointer?

Comment: ARM EABI tells that SP should be 8 byte aligned, in which case you have it aligned to 8? Are you writing assembly?

Comment: Yes auslen I am trying to write in assembly

Comment: I think one easy way to achieve that when you are writing assembly always push 2 registers together even you don't use them - so don't push odd number of registers. I don't know if it is an idiom but that would make your life easier then specifically rounding up or down which could have change according to hw conf. (most likely not :))

Comment: @auselen would you please add it in your answer ,I am doing it in two instruction like and r4, sp, #4 , sub sp, sp, r4 ,Do know is it fine or not

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to align `sp` manually yourself, instead `push` one more register to get alignment. For example instead of

```
push {r3, r4, lr}
```

add one more register to the list to get alignment to 8 easily.

```
push {r1, r3, r4, lr}
```

This may feel like extra memory access but in general caches works with wider bit vectors than native word sizes.

Another note is also, you don't need to force yourself to get stack alignment right if you are not doing external calls or receiving. So if you have closed box assembly routine which doesn't make calls to external world or receive some, you can live with broken stack alignment as long as it doesn't bite your own loadings.

Comment: Thanks ausleen for your answer but still don't get how pushing an extra register to stack will make sp 8 byte aligned and how I integrate it to a simple IRQ handler where before calling C dispatch routine I have to aligen the sp from 4 byte to 8 byte.

Comment: Question is then why it is not 8 byte aligned to begin with?

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka13552.html

Comment: SP is automatically 8-byte aligned at the time your code gets executed, provided the caller complies AtPCS(It does, doesn't it?). Don't worry.

Answer (score 1):

To move a pointer *up* to the nearest 8 byte boundary, but leave it unmodified if it's already a multiple of 8 (pseudo-code - you'll need to add some casts if doing this in C):

```
p = (p + 7) & ~7;
```

or similarly to move it *down* to the nearest 8 byte boundary:

```
p = p & ~7;
```

Comment: Say I have point to address 0100(4 byte aligned) and doing p=p&~7 gives me value 0 ,then how it would be 8 byte aligned?

Comment: If p = 100 (decimal) then `p = p & ~7` will make p = 96.

Comment: Sorry @Paul but I mean 0100 in Binary which will be 4 in decimal.

Comment: OK - a value of 4 decimal would become 0 as expected, which is a multiple of 8. Anything which is not already a multiple of 8 would be rounded down to the nearest multiple of 8.

Comment: Yes @Paul ,got your point, 0 is multiple of every other number.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the decreasing stack

```
bic sp, sp, #7
```

should suffice.  With EABI, you can use `r12` or `r0-r3` to (re)store the previous value.

All this should be done only in assembly; within C you can rely on correctly aligned stack pointer and trying to change it there will probably crash your program.

Compilers take care about correct alignment; misaligned stacks can happen when calling interrupts.  Some CPUs (e.g. Cortex-M3) have special registers (STKALIGN) which can be used to enter irqs with 8-bit stack alignment.

Comment: @encs same doubt I have here which I pointed out to paul ,if I have  SP which is 4 byte aligned say sp=0x4 which is in binary 0100 ,now doing bic sp,sp,#7 will give me sp=0 which is not 8 bytes aligned at all.

Comment: Sorry @encs I didn't get you ,are you saying sp==0 is 8 byte aligned?

Comment: oh I really was confused here.sp==0 is also 4 byte agined ,right?

Comment: yes; and 23 byte and 42 byte aligned too ;)  It's probably the most-aligned address at all

Comment: so any address lke 0x0 ,0x8 0x16,0x24 and 0x32 is 8 byte aligned ,right?

Comment: You cannot use r12 or r0-r3 to hold the previous SP, because those registers are not preserved by subroutines in the AAPCS. You can use r4-r8, r10 or r11 to do so.

Comment: @Dr.KoutheirAttouchi the oppsite is true; you must not touch `r4-r11` because they must be restored when leaving the function.  But `r0-r3` and `r12` can be used freely.

Comment: If you align SP inside your own function for your own purpose, then what you said right, but if you align SP in order to invoke a subroutine, then what I said is right.

Comment: @Dr.KoutheirAttouchi ok; but when calling another function, you know your `SP` misalignment and can subtract a constant before calling this function (and add it afterwards).  Adjusting SP without knowing the exact misalignment might be needed e.g. when called by an interrupt.

Comment: There are other cases where misalignment of SP might not be easily known, outside of interrupt handlers, such as a high level language interpreter made of assembler stubs (templates).

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing leaf functions(no subroutine calls), don't bother.

You are perfectly fine with a 4-byte aligned SP since this requirement is due to ldrd and strd instructions that need the address being a multiple of eight.
Therefore, if the function you are writing doesn't call any subroutine unknown to you, there really is no need for that. (ldrd and strd are so rarely used anyway)

The SP is already 8-byte aligned when your function is called from a higher level language anyway.

If you want the SP to be 8-byte aligned, either don't touch it, or preserve only even number of registers.

Comment: Thanks @Jake would this call will align the stack pointer 8 byte aligned STMD sp!,{r0-r3,r12,r14},if so then how preserving even number of registers will align sp to 8 byte?

Comment: Also in this link http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka13552.html ,interrupt handling in armv7 there is explicit effort to align the sp to 8 bytes with AND r1,r1,#4 SUB sp,sp,r1.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a situation where you don't control the value of `SP` that you got, and you want to align `SP` on 8 bytes boundary (for example, to call a subroutine), then the following sequence does that, without using any other registers:

```
; Check if SP is aligned on 8 bytes boundary.
tst sp, #0x7
; If SP is aligned on 8 bytes boundary, then we skip a word on the stack
; and then save SP. This consumes 8 bytes on the stack but keeps SP
; aligned on 8 bytes boundary.
streq sp, [sp, #-8]!
; If SP is aligned on 4 bytes boundary, then we save SP. This consumes
; 4 bytes on the stack and also aligns SP on 8 bytes boundary.
strne sp, [sp, #-4]!
; Here, SP is aligned on 8 bytes boundary, and the previous value of SP
; is stored on the top of the stack.

; For example, let's call some subroutine...
blx lr

; In order to restore the original value of SP, just load the value
; at the top of the stack.
ldr sp, [sp]
```

Notice that the code above assumes that:

- You're running either in ARM 32-bits mode (e.g., ARMv5, ARMv6, ARMv7, AArch32,...).
- `SP` is be aligned at least on 4 bytes boundary, which is usually the case as the stack is viewed as an array of words.