# Why does STMDB/LDMIA etc increase/decrease four instead of eight?

Tags: assembly, arm

So I was having this class and found out the following code:

```
    STMIA SP, { R0 }
```

Does the following:

```
SP = SP + 4
[SP] = R0
```

I might be wrong, I am not sure. However most resources I searched on the internet shows this result. So what I am asking is, why isn't it `SP = SP + 8`? The register should hold 8 bits, right? Or does it mean something else?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want the stack to be 8byte aligned, the traditional way is to use `stmia SP, {r0, pc}`.  The `pc` is used to pad the stack and it is slightly useful to know who wrote the value when examining the stack.  Ie, just [add some extra register to the store set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20071466/aligning-a-stack-pointer-8-byte-from-4-byte-in-arm-assembly).  The [ARM ABI has a requirement to pad the stack to 8 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25282466/why-procedure-call-standard-for-the-arm-architecture-aapcs-requires-sp-to-be), which is why I think you asked this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, ARM registers actually hold *32* bits<sup>(a)</sup>, which is four bytes.

And it's that four *bytes* which is being used to modify the stack pointer.

Stacks are rarely bit-addressable so the only use case where you would modify by eight is if your registers were 64 bits in size.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> This may not be the case for the newer 64-bit AArch64 ones, which I believe may have wider registers but, if those were the ones you were talking about, the code would be almost certainly adjusting by eight rather than four.

Comment: Yes, AArch64 has 64-bit registers x0..x31.  Their low halves are w0..w31.  But AArch64 removed the microcoded `ldmia`/`stmdb`, instead providing only the more RISCy `ldp` / `stp` load/store pair instructions.  (Still with the option of an addressing mode that writes back to the pointer register, making it usable as a push or pop.)  I *think* that unlike x86-64, AArch64 can thus "push"/"pop" 32-bit `w` registers as well as full 64-bit registers, if for some reason you want to.