# Why IAR ARM Cortex-M compiler does not align stack on 8-byte boundary?

Tags: c, arm, embedded, callstack, abi

ARM ABI says that the stack should be 8-byte aligned, but I see cases where the stack is aligned only to 4-byte boundary.

For example, I have the following simple busy-delay function:

```
void delay(int iter) {
   int volatile counter = 0;
   while (counter < iter) { // delay loop
       ++counter;
   }
}
```

This compiles with IAR EWARM 9.10.2 on ARM Cortex-M to the following disassembly:

```
SUB SP, SP, #0x4
...
ADD SP, SP, #0x4
BX LR
```

The problem is that after `SUB SP,SP,4` the stack is misaligned (is aligned only to 4-byte boundary).

Why is this happening? Is this compliant with the ARM ABI? Are there any compiler options to control that?

This question is related, but not a duplicate of: [Aligning a Stack pointer 8 byte from 4 byte in ARM assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20071466/aligning-a-stack-pointer-8-byte-from-4-byte-in-arm-assembly)

Comment: provide a complete example?

Comment: @old_timer: Thanks for looking into this. There is really not much to complete here. During the whole execution of the delay() function (which is intentionally long) the stack is misaligned. If an interrupt comes during that time, it will see such a misaligned stack, so the exception stack frame would have to include the extra "stack aligner" word. I thought that this is exactly why ARM ABI demands 8-byte stack alignment and the compiler should not leave the stack like that.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Nate's answer about the stack not requiring to be aligned at all times, you mentioned in a comment that you are interested in the behaviour when an interrupt occurs.

As long as you do not modify the control register bit CCR.STKALIGN from its default value of 1, then the hardware will automatically align the stack to 8 bytes on exception entry.  Also, the return value which the hardware puts in the link register contains a flag to tell it to restore the correct stack pointer value on exception return.  Software doesn't need to know about this at all, your interrupt handler can just be an AAPCS compliant function which is allowed to assume 8 byte stack alignment on entry.

For more details see the [ARMv7M ARM](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0403/latest) section B1.5.7.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0375/g/Compiler-Features/Compiler-eight-byte-alignment-features

> The Procedure Call Standard for the ARM Architecture (AAPCS) requires that the stack is eight-byte aligned **at all external interfaces**.

This means that the stack must be eight-byte aligned when calling an ABI-compliant function.  This alignment is not required to be maintained at all times.  Since this code does not make any function calls while the stack is misaligned, it is legal.

So your interrupt handler needs to be written to properly handle a potentially misaligned stack.

Comment: The interrupt handler does not need to handle this, the hardware interrupt entry process aligns the stack automatically.  See ARMv7M ARM section B1.5.7.